# Can you update a set in a redis hashmap without pulling the whole hashmap to update?

Tags: python, redis

Let's say I have a hashmap that looks like so:

```
{'dog': {'A': set([1,2,3]), 'B': set([1,2,3])},
 'cat': {'A': set([1,2,3]), 'B': set([1,2,3])}
 ....
}
```

And now after some time, I want to add the values `[2,5,8]` to `dog->B` so that the resulting hashmap becomes

```
{'dog': {'A': set([1,2,3]), 'B': set([1,2,3,5,8])},
 'cat': {'A': set([1,2,3]), 'B': set([1,2,3])}
 ....
}
```

Is this possible without pulling the whole hashmap to update?

Unfortunately, doing something like this only replaces the value entirely.

```
conn = redis.Redis('localhost')
dict = {'A': set([1,2,3]), 'B': set([4,5,6])}
conn.hmset('Cats', dict)
print(conn.hgetall('Cats'))
dict = {'A': set([4,3,5]), 'B': set([1,2,3])}
conn.hmset('Cats', dict)
print(conn.hgetall('Cats'))

output:
{b'A': b'{1, 2, 3}', b'B': b'{4, 5, 6}'}
{b'A': b'{3, 4, 5}', b'B': b'{1, 2, 3}'}
```

Is there an `conn.sadd` that I can use to go into the hashmap and into the set? Right now my way around this is by constructing a key that contains both the animal and the key inside the animal's hashmap.

```
conn.sadd('{}-{}'.format('Cat', 'A'), entry['Pet'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no command to add/remove from hash fields, you will have to read the value and update it to new value and set it again

```
conn = redis.Redis('localhost')
dict = {'A': set([1,2,3]), 'B': set([4,5,6])}
conn.hmset('Cats', dict)
print(conn.hgetall('Cats'))
```

Now if you want to add [7,8,9] to Cats>B, then

```
b = set(eval(hmget('Cats', 'B')))
b = b.union(set([7,8,9]))
conn.hset('Cats', {'B': b})
print(conn.hgetall('Cats'))
```

Outputs:

```
{b'A': b'{1, 2, 3}', b'B': b'{4, 5, 6}'}
{b'A': b'{1, 2, 3}', b'B': b'{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}'}
```

Another alternative is to use redis sets, by including the hash fields with redis keys, Like below

```
conn.sadd('Cats#A', *[1, 2, 3])
conn.sadd('Cats#B', *[4, 5, 6])
print(conn.smembers('Cats#A'))
print(conn.smembers('Cats#B'))
conn.sadd('Cats#B', *[7, 8, 9])
print(conn.smembers('Cats#B'))
```

Outputs:

```
{b'[1, 2, 3]'}
{b'[4, 5, 6]'}
{b'[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'}
```

Use whichever is more easy to manage.

Comment: I've taken the `Cats#A` approach.